# Weird bug of Multi-language NSString. Maybe issue of Encoding

Tags: ios, encoding, ios6, nsstring

I think NSString has weird bug with multi-lingual support.

I am developing in iOS SDK 6.0 and same issue both on simulator and iPhone.

This is my code.

```
 NSString* localPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
 NSLog(@"%@",localPath);
 NSLog(@"%@",@"/Users/vicjames/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/8186A14C-1482-44AB-AD3A-0A88DC40EC89/Documents/Data/해부학/11월 29일/095. Michael Learns to Rock - 25 Minutes.mp3");

 NSLog(@"localPath Length:%d",[localPath length]);
 NSLog(@"String Length:%d",[@"/Users/vicjames/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/8186A14C-1482-44AB-AD3A-0A88DC40EC89/Documents/Data/해부학/11월 29일/095. Michael Learns to Rock - 25 Minutes.mp3" length]);


 NSLog(@"localPath : URL: %@",[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:localPath] absoluteString]);
 NSLog(@"String URL: %@",[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/vicjames/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/8186A14C-1482-44AB-AD3A-0A88DC40EC89/Documents/Data/해부학/11월 29일/095. Michael Learns to Rock - 25 Minutes.mp3"] absoluteString]);
```

The logs below is execution result of code.

```
2012-12-23 00:11:57.741 AudioArchive[11702:c07] /Users/vicjames/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/8186A14C-1482-44AB-AD3A-0A88DC40EC89/Documents/Data/해부학/11월 29일/095. Michael Learns to Rock - 25 Minutes.mp3
2012-12-23 00:11:57.741 AudioArchive[11702:c07] /Users/vicjames/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/8186A14C-1482-44AB-AD3A-0A88DC40EC89/Documents/Data/해부학/11월 29일/095. Michael Learns to Rock - 25 Minutes.mp3
```

Two strings looks same.

```
2012-12-23 00:11:57.742 AudioArchive[11702:c07] localPath Length:194
2012-12-23 00:11:57.742 AudioArchive[11702:c07] String Length:186
```

But has different length.

```
2012-12-23 00:11:57.743 AudioArchive[11702:c07] localPath : URL: file://localhost/Users/vicjames/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/8186A14C-1482-44AB-AD3A-0A88DC40EC89/Documents/Data/%E1%84%92%E1%85%A2%E1%84%87%E1%85%AE%E1%84%92%E1%85%A1%E1%86%A8/11%E1%84%8B%E1%85%AF%E1%86%AF%2029%E1%84%8B%E1%85%B5%E1%86%AF/095.%20Michael%20Learns%20to%20Rock%20-%2025%20Minutes.mp3
2012-12-23 00:11:57.743 AudioArchive[11702:c07] String URL: file://localhost/Users/vicjames/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/8186A14C-1482-44AB-AD3A-0A88DC40EC89/Documents/Data/%ED%95%B4%EB%B6%80%ED%95%99/11%EC%9B%94%2029%EC%9D%BC/095.%20Michael%20Learns%20to%20Rock%20-%2025%20Minutes.mp3
```

URL encoding shows the difference.

```
2012-12-23 00:11:57.745 AudioArchive[11702:c07] is Not Equal
```

Also NSString says that two strings are not equal.

1. I want to know why this things are happening.
2. Should I consider internal NSString encoding?
3. If I should, how can I convert or deal with internal encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS filesystem names are in [normalization form D](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/), whereas  your string literal is in normalization form C.

You can get the same length by normalizing it to form C first:

```
NSLog(@"localPath Length:%d",[[localPath precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] length]);
```

Comment: Thanks!! As you replied, this code solves all the problems~
"    localPath = [localPath precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];   "